# Count Correct Answers

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet to automatically grade test answers.
Column A has question numbers (from paper sheet), column B has the correct answers, and columns C,D,E... have student answers.

```
#    | Answer | Student A | Student B | Student C | Student D
-------------------------------------------------------------
1    |   A    | A         | A         | C         | A
2    |   B    | B         | B         | B         | B
3    |   C    | C         | C         | B         | C
```

I'd like to add a row above the headers that shows the number of correct answers for each student, but I can't seem to get the variables right. I'm using the formula `=$B2` for conditional formatting, and that works fine. I've tried

```
ACOUNT(FILTER()), SUMIF, COUNTIF
```

I think I want something to the effect of

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B152=C2:C152,1,0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff)¹ should be sufficient.

```
=sumproduct(--(C3:C5=$B3:$B5))
```

Lock the column references to the answers so the formula can be filled right.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>The documentation link is for MS-Office, Excel but the syntax is identical.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This single arrayFormula should work:

```
=mmult(SPLIT(rept("1|",COUNTA(B3:B)),"|"),ArrayFormula(--(C3:F5=B3:B5)))
```

Paste it in C1 and see the result:

[image]

---

To make formula work, when new rows added:

```
=mmult(SPLIT(rept("1|",COUNTA(B3:B)),"|"),
ArrayFormula(--(OFFSET(B3,,,COUNTA(B3:B))=OFFSET(C3:F3,,,COUNTA(B3:B)))))
```

[image]